# Flutter: No virtual method getLongVersionCode(), Sdk 29

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter: No virtual method getLongVersionCode(), Sdk 29

**Anybody knows how to fix this?**

> **No virtual method getLongVersionCode()**
>
> Plase see output: *Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
> E/AndroidRuntime(18676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(18676): Process: com.example.test, PID: 18676
> E/AndroidRuntime(18676): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method >getLongVersionCode()J in class Landroid
>
> /content/pm/PackageInfo; or its super classes (declaration of

Comment: This just happend to me also, after flutter upgrade to latest version `1.27.0-5.0.pre.62, on Linux`. Worked before the upgrade. Using Samsung G7, Android 8.0.0

Comment: For me, the problem went away after changing from master channel to beta. Seems like master is somewhat broken today. @nozip You my want to check your flutter version and channel

Answer (score 0):

[getLongVersionCode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo#getLongVersionCode()) was introduced with API28, pretty new. you are probably supporting older ones, so on these you can't execute this method/obtain version code from `PackageInfo`, because there is `NoSuchMethod` in API